# Golang Array of functions in function argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go

Playing around with `golang` parquet package and came across the function `s3.NewS3FileWriter` that accepts the following arguement `[]func(*s3manager.Uploader)`

```
func NewS3FileWriter(
    ctx context.Context,
    bucket string,
    key string,
    uploaderOptions []func(*s3manager.Uploader),
    cfgs ...*aws.Config,
) (source.ParquetFile, error) {
    if activeS3Session == nil {
        sessLock.Lock()
        if activeS3Session == nil {
            activeS3Session = session.Must(session.NewSession())
        }
        sessLock.Unlock()
    }

    file := &S3File{
        ctx:             ctx,
        client:          s3.New(activeS3Session, cfgs...),
        writeDone:       make(chan error),
        uploaderOptions: uploaderOptions,
        BucketName:      bucket,
        Key:             key,
    }

    return file.Create(key)
}
```

What does `[]func(*s3manager.Uploader)` mean? And how do I pass a modified version of `s3Manager.Uploader`? If I wanted to change the defaults for example.

Comment: Read it from left to right: Slice of function with argument pointer to s3manager.Uploader.

Comment: Hi, are you able to provide an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uploaderOptions` argument of `NewS3FileWriter` need to be filled with **slice of functions** during call. And each of the functions must have an argument with type of `*s3manager.Uploader`.

Example:

```
uploaderOptions := make([]func(*s3manager.Uploader), 0)

uploader1 := func (param *s3manager.Uploader) {
    fmt.Println("uploader 1", param)
}
uploaderOptions = append(uploaderOptions, uploader1)

uploader2 := func (param *s3manager.Uploader) {
    fmt.Println("uploader 2", param)
}
uploaderOptions = append(uploaderOptions, uploader2)

// ...

NewS3FileWriter(ctx, bucket, key, uploaderOptions)
```

Comment: Thanks - appreciate that